# How can I add and resize images from URLs into an HTML canvas using fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, fabricjs, loading

I have an array with a bunch of images:

```
const imgSrcs = ["dashavatar1.jpg", "dashavatar2.jpg", "dashavatar 3.jpg"];
```

And I'm creating image object from that using the `Image` constructor:

```
const images = [];

for (i = 0; i < imgSrcs .length; i++) {
  const image = new Image();
  images.push(image);
}
```

Now I want to assign the image source and add these image objects on the canvas using `fabric.js`.

Comment: use imagearray[i].src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load those images first using [`const img = new Image()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image), wait until they are loaded using [`image.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images) and then use [`ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) to render it into the canvas:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const innerWidth = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
const innerHeight = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const images = [
  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5XWd.png',
  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnOAO.png',
];

images.forEach((src, i) => {
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = src;

  image.onload = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(image, innerWidth / 2 - 16, 8 + 40 * i, 32, 32);
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

With `frabric.js` you would do the same thing but using their own [`fabric.Image.fromUR`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#.fromURL) function:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
const innerWidth = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
const innerHeight = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const images = [
  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5XWd.png',
  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnOAO.png',
];

canvas.setWidth(innerWidth);
canvas.setHeight(innerHeight);

images.forEach((src, i) => {
  fabric.Image.fromURL(src, (image) => {
    const oImage = image.set({
      left: canvas.getWidth() / 2 - 16,
      top: 8 + 40 * i,
      scaleX: 32 / image.width,
      scaleY: 32 / image.height,
      scale: 1,
    });
  
    canvas.add(oImage);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes buddy it worked ! but I want to do it using fabric.js library file to get image resizing feature

Comment: @ajinkya Just updated the answer with fabric.js' version. 